# Order by Select into variable mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have the following sql query:

```
Select
sum(
    (IF(notification_type = 'qAccepted',credit*0.5,0)) + 
    (IF(notification_type = 'creditScored',credit,0)) +
    (IF(notification_type = 'flagPositive',credit,0))
) into b_credit
from notifications n
left join user_answers ua on ua.question_id = n.question_id and ua.user_id = n.user_id 
left join user_credits uc on uc.user_id = n.user_id
where (unix_timestamp() - timestamp) < 7*86400  
group by n.user_id  
order by b_credit desc 
limit 1;
```

How can I order by the `b_credit` variable?

**Edit**
This makes the `b_credit` variable NULL. The procedure runs fine.

Comment: Updated the question. There is no error but the variable has null value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT MAX(x_credit) INTO b_credit
FROM (
    Select
    sum(
        (IF(notification_type = 'qAccepted',credit*0.5,0)) + 
        (IF(notification_type = 'creditScored',credit,0)) +
        (IF(notification_type = 'flagPositive',credit,0))
    ) AS x_credit
    from notifications n
    left join user_answers ua on ua.question_id = n.question_id and ua.user_id = n.user_id 
    left join user_credits uc on uc.user_id = n.user_id
    where (unix_timestamp() - timestamp) < 7*86400
    group by n.user_id
) x
```

Comment: I get the error 'Every derived table must have its own alias' while trying to save the stored procedure

Comment: That's what the alias `x` is for.

Comment: Ah, got it. Implementing now.

Comment: @Barmar . . . do you know why the OP's original query fails?  That syntax should work for what s/he wants.

Comment: I think `INTO` may be executed before `LIMIT`, so it's doing it for every row, and that doesn't make sense.

Comment: Actually, doing the `into` before the `limit` doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Barmar . . . Except the documentation explicitly says "If it is possible that the statement may retrieve multiple rows, you can use LIMIT 1 to limit the result set to a single row."  (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html).  The example is not with an `order by`, but I wonder if this is an error that should be reported to MySQL.

Comment: Now I'm not sure why your original was failing. A simplified version works for me here: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ad6b8/4